# ctx.message.channel.edit not running everytime command is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, discord, discord.py

So, I currently have this command to change the title of a channel in discord with discord py. The command works a few times in each channel then subsequently breaks on a per channel basis (or finishes the command around 6+min later).

```
import api
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["pp.", "Pp.", "PP.", "pP."])
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def progress_update(ctx, new_emoji):
    if ctx.message.channel.name[0] not in ["", "", "", ""]:
        await ctx.send("That is not a valid channel to run **progress_update** in.\nPlease run this command in a challenge channel")
        return

    if new_emoji not in ["", "", "", ""]:
        await ctx.send("That is not a valid emoji.\nPlease use one of the following: , , , ")
        return

    new_name = new_emoji + ctx.message.channel.name[1:]
    temp = await ctx.message.channel.edit(name=new_name)
    await ctx.send("Progress updated!")

client.run(api.api)
```

I am stumped as to what the problem can be. It only appears to be happening on the `ctx.message.channel.edit` command, as I can still view the error messages (in the `not it` statements) if I type the command wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely hitting ratelimits. You can only change the name or the topic of a channel twice per 10 minutes. Thankfully discord.py handles ratelimits by itself and you don't get an error. You can also see this if you enable logging.

though, do be aware, your console is going to get spammed with every request your bot makes to discord API, you can set a more specific logging to mitigate this. Just a heads up.

Read more about setting up logging [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/logging.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense.